# How do I use jq to merge an array in a base file from files in subfolders

Tags: azure-pipelines, jq

I've runto a stumbling block trying to use jq in an Azure Pipeline (I'm sure it's not helped, because I'm not a Linux guy)

I have multiple (unknown how many at runtime) subdirectories, each has a file named object.json with the identical structure. All json files in here simplified as much as necessary, and I don't think any more than that.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "genericInformation": {
        "value": {
          "value1": "Something",
          "value2": "Otherthing"
        }
      },
      "objects": {
        "value": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "Object1",
            "Container": "Container1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

I am looking to build a single file at the root level of the structure combining the objects.value array entries from all files into one file. I also have a file with an empty array I can merge them into

(Desired Output)

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "genericInformation": {
        "value": {
          "value1": "Something",
          "value2": "Otherthing"
        }
      },
      "objects": {
        "value": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "Object1",
            "Container": "Container1"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "Name": "Object2",
            "Container": "Container2"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "Name": "Object3",
            "Container": "Container3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

This loop doesn't quite get me what I want, instead it seems to be appending the output of each run of the loop to the output file, so I think I'm close.

```
cp noobjects.json allobjects.json
for objectFile in `ls -d OBJ*/`
do
  jq -s ".[0].parameters.objects.value += .[1].parameters.objects.value | .[0]" allobjects.json $objectfile/object.json  
done | jq -s . > allobjects.json
```

My thinking with the code was to start with an empty array, then loop through all the subfolders (ones that start with OBJ) and Add the objects.value contents from the current file to the allobjects file.

With three subdirectories, I ended up with something like this.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "genericInformation": {
        "value": {
          "value1": "Something",
          "value2": "Otherthing"
        }
      },
      "objects": {
        "value": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "Object1",
            "Container": "Container1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "genericInformation": {
        "value": {
          "value1": "Something",
          "value2": "Otherthing"
        }
      },
      "objects": {
        "value": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "Object1",
            "Container": "Container1"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "Name": "Object2",
            "Container": "Container2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}

{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "genericInformation": {
        "value": {
          "value1": "Something",
          "value2": "Otherthing"
        }
      },
      "objects": {
        "value": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "Object1",
            "Container": "Container1"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "Name": "Object2",
            "Container": "Container2"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "Name": "Object3",
            "Container": "Container3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find` to get the files, `xargs` to feed them into `jq`, and therein `reduce` to put them together:

```bash
find . -name object.json | xargs jq 'reduce inputs as $in (.; 
  .parameters.objects.value += $in.parameters.objects.value
)'
```

If you have more files than would fit into your argument space, you can instruct `find` to just dump their content using `-exec cat`, as `jq` can handle a stream of JSON documents in almost the same manner:

```bash
find . -name object.json -exec cat {} \; | jq 'reduce inputs as $in (.;
  .parameters.objects.value += $in.parameters.objects.value
)'
```

Comment: Thanks pmf, I will give that a try. 2 questions though. 1. How do I combine that with the blank object file? Or do I just call it object.json instead? and 2. How do I write the output to a file? I need it to be an on-disk file to be processed by later steps in the pipeline

Comment: @NLInnett (1) I took the first file as base, and added all others to it. If you want to use a blank file instead, provide it after the jq filter, so it becomes the first one read, e.g. `… | xargs jq 'reduce … (…)' blank.json`. (2) To write the output into a file, redirect it using `>`, e.g. `find … | > out.json xargs jq …`.

Comment: Thanks pmf, I used for first suggestion (for now) and it works like a charm. If I could send you a beer I would (or beverage of your choice!).